# How do I generate iframes from a JSON using EJS?

Tags: json, sails.js, ejs

I have a JSON with an attribute 'link', whose value is a URL.
I want to iterate over all these links and generate iframes for all of these.

I'm using Sails with EJS. Here's my .ejs file:

```
<div>
<h1>This is <%= pageTitle %></h1>
    <% for (var i=0 ; i < graphs[0].layouts.default.graphs.length ; i++) {%>
        <iframe src="<%= graphs[0].layouts.default.graphs[i].link %>" height="<%= graphs[0].layouts.default.graphs[i].height %>" width="<%= graphs[0].layouts.default.graphs[i].width %>" />
    <% } %>
</div>
```

I'm getting just one iframe, for the first link.

Can someone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div>
<h1>This is <%= pageTitle %></h1>
<% for (var i=0 ; i < graphs[0].layouts.default.graphs.length ; i++) {%>
    <iframe src="<%= graphs[0].layouts.default.graphs[i].link %>" height="<%= graphs[0].layouts.default.graphs[i].height %>" width="<%= graphs[0].layouts.default.graphs[i].width %>" ></iframe>
<% } %>
</div>
```

Comment: I remember how just adding a </iframe> tag solved the issue for me back then. Thanks for the answer!